# Texto rolando em bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Estou utilizando uma `<ul>` para mostrar os resultados em um site. São printados 3 itens por linha: Nome do site, link e status.

No navegador o resutlado é bom:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O poblema ocorre quando utilizo o mobile:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por eu não estar utilizando uma tabela (nem pretendo), os textos se sobrepõem e o resultado fica bagunçado.

Gostaria que o primeiro campo (nome) ficasse "scrollando" automaticamente e continuamente na horizontal, ocupando apenas um pequeno espeço. Já procurei em diversos lugares e não encontrei uma boa maneira de fazer isso.

Comment: Pedro por favor não leve a mal, mas pensando no usuário imagina o cidadão tendo que esperar um nome gigante scrollar até o fim, na verdade ele nem sabe onde é o fim e nem o tempo que vai ter que esperar, e se por pior ele não ver a última palavra ainda vai ter que esperar o bagulho voltar todo para um lado e começar de novo... olha que péssima experiencia de uso... Mas é só uma opinião ok. em telas pequenas assim, eu quebraria o texto grande acima em uma linha e o link e statos em outra linha, um na direita e outro na esquerda usando só o grid do Bootstrap. Se quiser faço um exemplo.

Comment: Teria que ver tb o campo do link que não fica cabendo no espaço na versão mobile.

Comment: Vlw pelas críticas pessoal, não tinha pensado no quão isso poderia ser ruim para o usuário. Vou pensar na melhor opção e posto aqui o resultado.